# $\triangle ABC$ with circumcenter $K$ has $AB=AC$ and $AD=BC$. Find $\angle BAC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> In a triangle, $AB = AC$ and $D$ is its circumcenter.  It is also known that $AD = BC$.  Find the measure of the $\angle BAC$.

Any tips for me being able to resolve the issue?  I tried to let k triangle inscribed.

Comment: What does this mean "and FOR your circumcenter"? Do you have a picture?

Comment: What is the point D ?

Comment: The point P lies in the middle of a line that goes from vertex B to D. D is between vertices A and C

Comment: D is any point on AC? Isnt D your circumcenter?

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming D is your circumcenter (and that there is a typo in your question)

Check that $AD=DB=DC=BC$

So first $\triangle DBC$ is equilateral. So angle $DBC=$ angle DCB $=60^{\circ}$

Also check that $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ADC$ are isosceles. So angles $ABD=BAD=DAC=DCA=\alpha$(say)

Using that the sum of all angles in a triangle is $180^{\circ}$, we get angle $BAC=2\alpha=30^\circ$

Another solution.

Imagine a circle anround the $\triangle ABC$. Since D is the center of your circle, the segment BC will subtend half the angle it subtends on the centre as it subtends on the cicumference. (half of $60^\circ$ )

Comment: The answer to the problem is to say 20

Comment: Please do the calculation once yourself, you will see which answer is right 20 or 30.@MeuluElisson . You don't even need to do the calculation. Just the diagram will tell you your answer.

Comment: Drawing an isosceles triangle so that the parallel to the base VC, which passes through E is the average basis of ABC if P is circunscentro AP = BP = CP.  APC isosceles with base angle = a

Comment: I did this way..

Comment: @MeuluElisson I guess you got the jist but messed up your notations. Please follow my solution(with notations) and you will reach the answer in no time

Comment: Okkk ............

Comment: @MeuluElisson Please incur the habit of accepting an answer if you are satisfied with it. (The small tick mark)

Comment: Your solution works when the triangle is acute (circumcenter inside the triangle). In the case of an obtuse triangle, you get the answer to be $150$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\measuredangle BAC=\alpha$ and $R$ be a radius of the circle.

Thus, by the law of sines we obtain:
$$R=2R\sin\alpha$$ or
$$\sin\alpha=\frac{1}{2},$$ which gives $$\alpha=30^{\circ}$$ or  $$\alpha=150^{\circ}$$

Comment: Law of sines in which triangle?

Comment: @Julian Mejia For $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: so you have $\frac{R}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{AC}{\sin(\angle ABC )}$. How do you get what you are claiming?

Comment: @Julian Mejia No! It's just $a=2R\sin\alpha.$ Law of sines it's: $\frac{a}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{b}{\sin\beta}=\frac{c}{\sin\gamma}=2R.$

Comment: I see, you are using  $\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=2R$. Usually when I refer to Law of sines is just the first three equalities.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Rozenberg is exact with two cases, but we can solve this issue with primary geometry.We always have $\triangle BDC$ is equilateral. But depending on the position of $D$ which is inside or outside of $\triangle ABC$ (in fact, $\triangle ABC$ is obtuse or acute), we have two cases.

Case 1: [image]

Case 2: [image]